# Stata simple key-value pairs

Tags: hashtable, stata

I am defining a categorical variable using a set of named rules. I want to put these rules in the preamble as "parameters" that I can easily change later. I'm wondering the best way to do this. I feel like a reproducible example is not needed here since I am asking -- generally -- what is a good way of setting parameters that essentially have a key-value structure in Stata?

This is the code I am using at the moment, to classify days in terms of dummies for weather events.

```
preserve 
clear
input str12 key str40 val
"Clear"         "!(event_thunder|event_snow|event_rain)"
"Rain"          "event_rain & !(event_thunder|event_snow)"
"Snow"          "event_snow & !(event_thunder|event_rain)"
"Rain & Snow"   "(event_snow & event_rain) & !event_thunder"
"Thunder"       "event_thunder"
end

scalar N_events = _N

forvalues i = 1/`=N_events'{
    scalar  event_key`i' = key[`i']
    scalar  event_val`i' = val[`i']
}
restore
```

Later in the code, I can iterate over my "key" and "val" scalars to define my categorical variable.

```
gen byte event = 0
forvalues i = 1/`=N_events'{
    local event_condition `=event_val`i''
    replace event = `i' if `event_condition'
}
```

I still haven't figured out the correct code for applying a label using my `event_key*` scalars. Any advice on that would also be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code, with some adjustments, is equivalent to this example:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto
keep make price foreign

preserve

    clear

    input str12 key str40 val
    "for_cheap"         "foreign & price < 10000"
    "hom_expen"         "!foreign & price >= 10000"
    end

    local numkeys = _N

    forvalues i = 1/`numkeys' {
        local  event_key`i' = key[`i']
        local  event_val`i' = val[`i']
    }

restore 

gen byte event = 0
forvalues i = 1/`numkeys' {
    replace event = `i' if `event_val`i''
}

save testing, replace
```

But you just want this, which produces the exact same result:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto
keep make price foreign

gen byte event = 0
replace event = 1 if foreign & price < 10000
replace event = 2 if !foreign & price >= 10000

// to test these results with previous
cf _all using testing, verbose
```

You can still put the conditions in locals, for example, and use that:

```
<snip>

local for_cheap foreign & price < 10000
local hom_expen !foreign & price >= 10000

gen byte event = 0
replace event = 1 if `for_cheap'
replace event = 2 if `hom_expen'
```

Furthermore, you could use loops instead of multiple `replace`s:

```
<snip>

local for_cheap "foreign & price < 10000"
local hom_expen "!foreign & price >= 10000"

local allcond for_cheap hom_expen
local n : word count `allcond'

gen byte event = 0
forvalues i = 1/`n' {
    local cond `:word `i' of `allcond'' // extended macro function
    replace event = `i' if ``cond''

    // syntax for value labels
    local lbl `lbl' `i' "`cond'" 
}

label define lblevent `lbl'
label values event lblevent

list in 1/25
```

That puts each named condition within another local called `allcond`. Then use the [*parallel lists*](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/looping-over-parallel-lists/) strategy to loop over. I've also added code for the value labels.

See also `help extended_fcn` to read on *extended macro functions* (which I've used).

If you want to declare the key/values only once, you can still do it using locals only:

```
clear

sysuse auto
keep make price foreign

local allcond for_cheap "foreign & price < 10000" ///
              hom_expen "!foreign & price >= 10000"

local n : word count `allcond'

gen byte event = 0
forvalues i = 2(2)`n' {

    // get label and condition (extended macro function)
    local condlbl `:word `=`i'-1' of `allcond''
    local cond `:word `i' of `allcond'' 

    // replace
    replace event = `=`i'/2' if `cond'

    // syntax for value labels
    local lbl `lbl' `=`i'/2' "`condlbl'"  
}

label define lblevent `lbl'
label values event lblevent
```

But at this point, your strategy of using a database (and my equivalent code) is easier to read.

By the way, depending on the rest of your code you could probably avoid `preserve/restore`. You could first `input` the key/values and then load the working database:

```
clear
set more off

// input key/val database

input str12 key str40 val
"for_cheap"         "foreign & price < 10000"
"hom_expen"         "!foreign & price >= 10000"
end

local numkeys = _N

forvalues i = 1/`numkeys' {
    local  event_key`i' = key[`i']
    local  event_val`i' = val[`i']
}

// load working database

clear

sysuse auto
keep make price foreign

gen byte event = 0
forvalues i = 1/`numkeys' {
    replace event = `i' if `event_val`i''
}

list
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative formulation; next time, I'll look for a way to ask using `sysuse` data, as you have. I was aware of the manually-set-each-value approach, but think it makes alterations more error-prone (whether changing the conditions or reordering them). I used scalars instead of locals because my locals frequently disappear. Sometimes, even when I define them at the command line, they don't show up under `macro list` immediately afterward. However, I agree that they are simpler insomuch as they save me from doing quote shenanigans. I'm sure I'll get the hang of them eventually.

Comment: Ah, I guess local and scalar quote usage looks similar here. Local is just preferred because it disappears?

Comment: Besides requiring manual numbering, the manually-set-each-condition setup doesn't let me write the name for my condition (later to be used as a label, like "Rain" above) close to the condition itself.

Comment: I've added code that puts the conditions in locals (that have a name). Then you can use them as desired. A `local` macro will be erased after execution is finished. A `global` macro won't, but their use is not in general recommended as you can generate clashes within different program spaces. Use them only if you really know what you are doing. The manuals, as always, are the best sources for help.

Comment: Can I iterate over the locals' names and use them as labels? Also, I'm still not clear, why local instead of scalar?

Comment: @Frank On the local/scalar comparison, another issue to consider is that scalars offer better numeric precision. This probably won't matter in your example. But scalars are preferred if subsequent complicated calculation is expected.

Comment: Yes, you can use the condition names for value labels. That was added to the code. On your question on locals/scalars, I still refer to the manual. Unless I always use the pseudo-function `scalar()` to refer to scalars, I will confuse variable names with scalar names, and this can be dangerous because if both use the same name, Stata will use the variable if the opposite is not indicated. Locals are clearly distinguished by the quotes used in (de)referencing them.

Comment: One final issue: editing conditions and debugging would be easier if it wasn't necessary to edit the definition of `allcond` whenever the set of conditions changes (whether by growing, shrinking or having a name changed). I suspect the `preserve`, `input`, `restore` sequence may be needed if I want to only write the `local`s' names in one place.

Comment: Finally, as far as I know, local macros cannot have spaces in their names (as in my example)...

Comment: I've added some code addressing your comment on "editing conditions and debugging".

Comment: The `include` command offers extra flexibility. You can put a series of local definitions in a do-file and then use `include` to run it. That way, you can edit the do-file and then re-run definitions. (I would worry about keeping an audit trail of changes to the dataset.)

Comment: Ah, it's nice to see that approach where you (Roberto Ferrer) parse a single `local`. While it may be harder to read the subsequent loop, it (i) leaves less chaff afterwards (like my plethora scalars or locals); (ii) doesn't require a separate dataset; and (iii) could probably be put into a program (once I know how to do that), so I'll keep it in mind. That's the sort of alternative I was hoping for initially, so I'll accept your answer. You are correct that I could do this whole thing before loading my real database and so don't need preserve/restore. Thanks for that idea about include, Nick.